# Como passo um a url de um servidor no java

Tags: java, spring, testes-de-unidade

Estou fazendo fazendo testes no meu projeto da faculdade, e estou com um seguinte problema. eu crio um objeto e passo todos os seus dados pelo setter e pelo construtor. Quando chamo o Service com o metodo de salvar, ele retorna Null e não consigo saber se está funcionando.

Pensei na solução de achar uma forma de passar a URL do servidor na classe de TEST, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola @rodrigo.oliveira,

use o [Spring MVC Test Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework) acredito que ele de suporte para o que precisa.

Comment: Olá,irei estudar sobre os MOCKs obrigado pela atenção.